# Trouble parsing this json response

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying  to parse the following json response:

```
[
    {
        "modelTrimList":{
            "modelTrim":[
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"5-DOOR",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6203,
                    "transmission":"Manual",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":16000,
                    "description":"5-Door",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion xb",
                    "curbWeight":0,
                    "@id":"81454531",
                    "effectiveDate":"4\/28\/10",
                    "displayName":"xB",
                    "deliveryFee":775
                },
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"5-DOOR",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6202,
                    "transmission":"Automatic",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":16950,
                    "description":"5-DOOR",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion xb",
                    "curbWeight":0,
                    "@id":"81454516",
                    "effectiveDate":"4\/28\/10",
                    "displayName":"xB",
                    "deliveryFee":720
                }
            ]
        },
        "name":"xB",
        "@id":"Scion xb"
    },
    {
        "modelTrimList":{
            "modelTrim":[
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"3 DOOR LIFTBACK",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6223,
                    "transmission":"Manual",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":18275,
                    "description":"2 DOOR L\/B",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion tC",
                    "curbWeight":3945,
                    "@id":"84604049",
                    "effectiveDate":"8\/6\/10",
                    "displayName":"tC",
                    "deliveryFee":720
                },
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"3 DOOR LIFTBACK",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6222,
                    "transmission":"Automatic",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":19275,
                    "description":"2 DOOR L\/B",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion tC",
                    "curbWeight":3945,
                    "@id":"84604028",
                    "effectiveDate":"8\/6\/10",
                    "displayName":"tC",
                    "deliveryFee":720
                }
            ]
        },
        "name":"tC",
        "@id":"Scion tC"
    },
    {
        "modelTrimList":{
            "modelTrim":[
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"5-DOOR",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6233,
                    "transmission":"Manual",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":15045,
                    "description":"5-DOOR",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion xd",
                    "curbWeight":3605,
                    "@id":"91724869",
                    "effectiveDate":"12\/8\/10",
                    "displayName":"xD",
                    "deliveryFee":775
                },
                {
                    "bodyStyle":"5-DOOR",
                    "cylinders":4,
                    "highwayMpg":0,
                    "modelCode":6232,
                    "transmission":"Automatic",
                    "cityMpg":0,
                    "msrp":15845,
                    "description":"5-DOOR",
                    "modelYear":2011,
                    "name":"Scion xd",
                    "curbWeight":3605,
                    "@id":"91724562",
                    "effectiveDate":"12\/8\/10",
                    "displayName":"xD",
                    "deliveryFee":775
                }
            ]
        },
        "name":"xD",
        "@id":"Scion xd"
    }
]
```

I can't seem to be parsing it correctly please advice and if possible a sample code that I could use, any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ - Your post, barring you editing it again, is valid JSON. Make sure what you're showing us is what you're parsing: This should be a copy/paste, and not subject to "typo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it with `[]`: right now it is not valid JSON.

EDIT: if it is properly wrapped, try this:

```
JSONArray js = new JSONArray(newjson);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),js.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),js.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
```

Comment: Agreed, something in your JSON looks off.

Comment: Sorry my bad it is wrapped in [] it's just a typo.

Comment: Well, I thought it was parsing, just only returning you a single member of the array?

Comment: Now that I have the right format for the json it'd not even getting me the first member of the array. So I edited the question and I posted the json response to be parsed. Thanks for taking ur time and help.

Comment: Update your post and include the actual java code you are using as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your JSON isn't valid, it looks like it should be an array of `modelTrimList`s

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to answer this is to run it through an online validation tool such as JSON Lint:

http://jsonlint.com/

With your example it suggested that you have an error on line 42:

Parse error on line 42:
...  "@id":"Scion xb"},{    "modelTrimLi
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF'

Comment: fixed the response thank you, but the problem is still there I can't seem to be parsing it right.